# pylint not-an-iterable error when subclassing List[int]

Tags: python, subclass, pylint

Code example:

```
from typing import List

class MyList(List[int]):
    def total(self) -> int:
        return sum(i for i in self)

a = MyList([1,2,3])
print(f'{a.total()=:}')
```

When I run it, it works

```
a.total()=6
```

But when I use pylint, I get the following error

```
...
toy.py:5:30: E1133: Non-iterable value self is used in an iterating context (not-an-iterable)
...
```

There are other pylint errors, but they're understandable. For the `not-an-iterable` problem, I don't quite understand it, am I subclassing `List[int]`, correctly?

I'm using Python-3.8, pylint==2.6.0

Comment: Is pylint on the latest version?

Comment: For the record pylint does not complain with `pylint 2.11.1, astroid 2.8.0, Python 3.9.2`. Have you tried with `class MyList(list[int]):` (lowercase `list`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded pylint to a more recent version.

```
pylint --version    
pylint 2.9.6
astroid 2.6.6
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 15 2021, 10:18:42)
```

and the error is gone.

Due to system constraints, I can't upgrade to the very latest version.